# how to build micro apps in iOS

Tags: ios

We have a requirement to build apps within an app, like how we have a main app called, Google and when we click the app icon, we get options like gmail, chrome ...and those apps function independently..How to organise these apps within the main app.

Could anyone give some basic idea on how to build micro-apps for iOS.

Comment: That flies directly against how mobile apps should work.  As a user, I don't want that experience on my iPhone - can you imagine what a drag it will be to get to the app I want to use? Also, updates will be monsters as it will update all the apps I don't use along with the ones I do.  What's the use-case for this? Is there any great user experience reason to do this? Please elaborate a bit so that we can understand your objective.  There's a reason apps are separate on mobiles, it's a better user experience.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, there is no such thing as a "micro app". What you seem to want to achieve is put various functions in one single app, what is not a good idea.

Thinking about your example with Google, they arent doing what you are mentioning. If the functionality is big enough, they put it in a seperate app (gmail, maps, ...). Same goes for you.

If you really want to go that way tho, i would highly suggest to make seperate storyboards for every "micro app" to keep things easier to maintain.

Comment: Consider that separate apps are going to be large. In this case, how can i load them on click of the main app icon. (like bunch of apps in single folder)

Comment: In this case i can only reference Ewald's comment on your question. In regards of user experience and updates, its just plain wrong to do what you are about to do. It's like 100% against every App architecture. App's should be as small and as specialized as possible, just to guarantee that the users are able to use it in an easy and understandable way.

Comment: The main app would just work like a hub for the other apps. User installs only apps they wanted. Is this still a bad approach?

Comment: I seriously dont know how this could work. I believe there is no function like "isAppXyzInstalled()" which you would need to show the "sub app" in your "hub app". Furthermore, how would you check which apps in the appstore belong to your "hub app"? Or would a user be able to use a "sub app" without installing the "hub app"? Honestly, what you are about to do is simply not possible.